# My Dynamic route doesn't seem to work in NextJS even if the code seems correct, gives 404 Error

Tags: reactjs, next.js, next.js13

I'm following a Weather App tutorial built in NextJS. The person i'm following is using the 'pages' structure while i'm having the 'app' structure. Everything works till i have a dynamic route that when should be used, the browser gives me a 404 error, and in the console i get 'GET http://localhost:3000/location/miami-4164138 404 (Not Found)'

The code for the Link is:

```
{query.length>3 && (
                <ul className='mt-28  w-8/12'>
                    {results.length>0 ? (
                        results.map((city) => (
                            <li key={city.slug} className='border-b-2 border-blue-500 mt-2 w-full hover:text-blue-900 hover:font-bold text-lg'>
                                {/* we want to return links */}
                                <Link href={`/location/${city.slug}`}>
                                        {city.name}
                                        {city.state ? `, ${city.state}` : ''}
                                        <span>({city.country})</span>
                                </Link>
                            </li>
                        ))
                    ) : (
                        <li>No results</li>
                    )}
                </ul>
            )}
```

I also added the folder structure.
The code in [city].js is:

```
    `export async function getServerSideProps(context) {

      const slug = context.params.city;
      return{
        props:{
          slug: slug
        }
      }
    }

    export default function City({slug}) {
    return (
        <div>
            <h1>City page</h1>
            <h2>{slug}</h2>
        </div>
      )
    }`
```

I really don't know how to fix it. Any help would be great
Given that the video is from 2 years ago i figured it might be some issues because of updates and such, but i looked at the documentation for the dynamic paths of Link in NextJS and everything looks okay. I have 0 ideas, learning on my own and don't know who to ask for help :')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're using the App Router, you'll need to move `[city].js` to `[city]/page.js`— see [this example](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/pages-and-layouts#pages) in the Next.js documentation.

Comment: Bless you, Caleb